# Window Location Reloads Infinite PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a "Add to Cart" button with Window Location sets to reload. But when I click it, it keeps on reloading infinitely or never stops. I just need it to reload so I can still browse for more items to Add to my cart. How can i set it on the same page?

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tut");

if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "product_id");
        if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
            $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
                'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
            );
            $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
            echo '<script>window.location.reload()</script>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<script>alert("Products already added to cart")</script>';
            echo '<script>window.location.reload()</script>';
        }
    }
    else {
        $item_array = array(
            'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }
}

if (isset($_GET["action"])) {
    if ($_GET["action"] == "delete") {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values) {
            if ($values["product_id"] == $_GET["id"]) {
                unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
                echo '<script>alert("Product has been removed")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location.reload()</script>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you reload the page using `window.location.reload()` it will definitely post the data again.

so try using the below work around

```
$currentpage_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo '<script>window.location.href="'.$currentpage_url.'";</script>';
```

Comment: I copy the code but It is not working, ("Object not found")